Upgrading appenging app with legacy bundled services from java 8 to java 17 runtime fails to deploy
We have an appengine standard java web app which uses appengine sdk extensively for almost all the key APIs of appengine e.g. datastore, search api, memcache, bigquery, cloudstorage etc. This runs on java 8 runtime for now.
Apart from this, we use DataNucleus appengine plugin to enhance JDO classes to interact with Cloud Datastore. As this web app is actually an API Backend so we use JERSEY 1.7 to write rest web services.
Now, due to end of support for Java 8 on GAE, we have decided to upgrade our app to Java 17 runtime. For this, we followed whay migration guide suggest on GCP documentation. Our appengine-web.xml has following two additions to support legacy bundled services on java 17 runtime :
<runtime>java17</runtime>
<app-engine-apis>true</app-engine-apis>

We are able to upgrade all our servlet code onto java 17 with legacy bundled services working fine on GAE Server.The problem arises when third party libraries like Jersey when migrated to Java 17 compatible version, say, 3.., it relies on jakarta.* namespace classes instead of javax.* classes. Hence it forces us to get rid of all javax.* classes and use jakarta.* classes instead.
We have replaced all our javax.* classes with jakarta.* classes in the project code. Project gets compiled successfully with jakarta.* dependencies now in place. We have also resolved any possible dependency conflict with old javax.* too. But when deployed this app on GAE/java17 with legacy bundled services, it throws errors as follows:
Request failed: Unexpected exception from servlet: java.lang.IllegalStateException: class com.myCompany.security.ApplicationSecurityFilter is not a javax.servlet.Filter
Request failed: Unexpected exception from servlet: javax.servlet.UnavailableException: Servlet class com.myCompany.server.someServlet is not a javax.servlet.Servlet**
It seems, even though, we have all jakarta.* libs in our  WEB-INF/lib folder of war file that gets deployed on GAE Server with java 17 runtime, it fails to find jakarta.* classes on GAE runtime.
Could anyone please suggest/point what are we doing wrong and what is the work around to overcome this issue?

I am looking forward to your feedback to understand whether the provided resolution has helped you in resolving the issue.

Thanks Sandeep. I am going to begin upgrade to java21 with EE8 and EE10 options whicheve works. Will update more as we progress on upgrade journey for java21 runtime ...

It seems like there was a known Issue tracker with Google App Engine updating their infrastructure from Jetty9 to Jetty11 to accommodate applications using the Jakarta namespace on java runtime 17.
Currently the team has provided an alternative workaround to use the latest updated java runtime 21 released which is based on jetty 12. The interesting thing is that Jetty 12 can support both the existing javax.servlet.* APIs as well as the new Jakarta APIs for maximum ease of use.
In case the above option is not a feasible one, You may raise a new Issue tracker or contact google support explaining your concern.

Thanks for taking time and suggesting the way ahead. As per GCP upgrade/migration documentation, we see option to jump upgrade to Java 21 instead of java 17. But really not sure if java21/EE10 would behave friendly with legacy bundled services and with java21/EE10, it is yet to verify if javax.* and jakarta.* coexist on GAE server runtime.

Actually, we had chosen to incrementally upgrade first to java17 and then java21 at later stage as we are on java 8. As java17/EE7 does not support jakarta.* classes, I believe, we are left with no choice but to upgrade to java21 with EE8 and EE10 options. Will update more as we begin our upgrade journey for java21...
